# Convert binary data to base64 does not work with btoa unescape

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, jpeg

I am new to React and want to display an image downloaded as binary data. I download the image data from api call to adobe lightroom api. The api call works since the image is displayed in Postman without problems. I can also save the image data to a jpeg-file and it is displayed ok.

In React I want to do  `` <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${theImage}`} /> `` and for that to work I need to convert the binary data to a base64 encoded string. When i convert the downloaded jpeg using `cat image.jpeg|base64 > base64.txt` the resulting string works in my React app.

But when I try `var theImage = btoa(binarydata)` in React I get `Unhandled Rejection (InvalidCharacterError): Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

After searching the issue I try use `var theImage = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( binarydata )))` and similar proposed solution but resulting strings from those does not turn out to be a valid base64 encodings of the jpeg as it seem (I try the result from the conversions in online base64->image services and no image is shown). I have also tried other proposed solution such as *base64-js* and *js-base64* libraries and non of those create a valid base64 valid image that can be shown in my React code.

How do you convert jpeg binary data to valid Base64 image encoding when `btoa` throws latin1 exception?

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't have a space after `base64,` in your `data` URI.

Comment: `unescape` (and its cousin `escape`) should never be used. They're broken holdovers from 1995. In particular, `unescape` is not the converse of `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: How are you getting `binarydata`? The error message is telling you that the problem is that `binarydata` is not a valid [binary string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary) (it has characters in it whose character code value is > 255).

Comment: I am getting it via an API call to Adobe lightroom API.  `const resp =  await axios.get('https://lr.adobe.io/v2/catalogs/<catalogid>/assets/${imageid}/renditions/thumbnail2x', {...`

 The call works in Postman (an Image is displayed). The docs are here: https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/lightroom/apidocs.html#/assets/getAssetRendition

Comment: That's only part of the story. What do you do with `resp` once you get it? How is the server sending the data? Note that you can't just dump a Blob or ArrayBuffer (for instance) into `btoa`.

Comment: Also I can download the jpeg image via cUrl and save to a valid jpeg. I can then base64 encode the file using cat myimage.jpeg|base64 > base64-encoded.txt and then that base64 string can be rendered in React as an image. It is the Javascript conversion that does not seem to work I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you're using `axios.get` to get the image from the server. What you'll presumably get back will be a `Buffer` or `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob`, etc., but it depends on what you do with the response you get from `axios`.

I don't use `axios` (never felt the need to), but you can readily get a `data` URI for binary data from the server via `fetch`:

```
// 1.
const response = await fetch("/path/to/resource");
// 2.
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
}
// 3.
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
// 4.
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
// 5.
const charArray = Array.from(byteArray, byte => String.fromCharCode(byte));
// 6.
const binaryString = charArray.join("");
// 7.
const theImage = btoa(binaryString);
```

Or more concisely:

```
const response = await fetch("/path/to/resource");
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
}
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const binaryString = Array.from(new Uint8Array(buffer), byte => String.fromCharCode(byte)).join("");
const theImage = btoa(binaryString);
```

Here's how that works:

1. We request the image data.
2. We check that the request worked (`fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors; those are reported via the `status` and `ok` props.
3. We read the body of the response into an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer); the buffer will have the binary image data.
4. We want to convert that buffer data into a [*binary string*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary). To do that, we need to access the bytes individually, so we create a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) (using that buffer) to access them.
5. To convert that byte array into a binary string, we need to convert each byte into its equivalent character, and join those together into a string.  Let's do that by using `Array.from` and in its mapping function (called for each byte), we'll use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to convert the byte to a character. (It's not really much of a conversion. The byte 25 [for instance] becomes the character with character code 25 in the string.)
6. Now we create the binary string by joining the characters in that array together into one string.
7. Finally, we convert that string to Base64.

---

Looking at the docs, it looks like `axios` lets you provide the option `responseType: "arraybuffer"` to get an array buffer. If I'm reading right, you could use `axios` like this:

```
const response = await axios.get("/path/to/resource", {responseType: "arraybuffer"});
const binaryString = Array.from(new Uint8Array(response.body), v => String.fromCharCode(v)).join("");
const theImage = btoa(binaryString);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the fetch version and don't get the conversion error so I get the correct Base64 enconding as far as I can see. 

However, I get `Unhandled Rejection (Error): HTTP error 200` and `Uncaught (in promise) Error: HTTP error 200`. and the image is still not shown. 

I am very new to React and Javascript so I guess I don't really understand how I should convert the await fetch code to something that does actually downloads the data and not get stuck in waiting for promise.

Comment: @MatsSkoglund - It's a bug in the answer, I missed out a `!` in what should be `if (!response.ok) {`. I've fixed it now. (Excellent description of the problem you had using the code in the answer, BTW, reading it I knew exactly what I'd done wrong.) Happy coding!

Comment: Right, @T:J.Crowder, I fixed the `!`. However, I now get `Unhandled Rejection (InvalidCharacterError): Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.` on the `const theImage = atob(binaryString);` line. I tried with `const theImage = btoa(binaryString);` instead and now it works. 

It was adding the 
`const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const binaryString = Array.from(new Uint8Array(buffer), v => String.fromCharCode(v)).join("");` that did it. I don't understand but now it works. 

Thanks very much!

Comment: @MatsSkoglund - Gah! I'm always typing `atob` when I mean `btoa`! Nice one figuring that out. I've updated the answer to add explanatory notes, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your image as a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/) and [generate a *blob:// URI*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) from it.

*data:// URLs* are completely inefficient and require far more memory space than blob:// URLs. The *data:// URL* takes 34% more space than the actual data it represents and it must be stored in the DOM + decoded as binary again to be read by the image decoder. The *blob:// URI* on the other hand is just a pointer to the binary data in memory.

*blob:// URLs* are not perfect, but until browsers implement `srcDoc` correctly, it's still the best we have.

So if as per the comments you are using axios in a browser, you can do

```
const blob = await axios.get("/path/to/resource", {responseType: "blob"});
const theImage = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

And if you want to use the *fetch* API

```
const response = await fetch("/path/to/resource");
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
}
const blob = await response.blob();
const theImage = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

---

Ps:
If you don't have any particular reason to fetch this image through AJAX (e.g credentials or special POST params), then pass directly the URL of the resource as the `src` of your image:

```html
<img src="/path/to/resource" />
```